# How to create one page Joomla site?

Tags: component, menu-item, menu, layout, joomla-3.5

what is the good way to create one page Joomla site?

I just need one or two module for each menu item. So, that would be okay with one page site.

I have a thought using external link as menu item, and put #something to it. But how is the exact step?
My intention is pretty simple, just like [this one](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/).

Any option (playing around with menu, menu items, module, component, OR hard code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any template should work fine with "External URL" menu options linking to appropriate IDs on the page (see example below).

[image: External Menu Option]

You can also create extra IDs in the content where needed by editing the HTML code like this:

```
<div id="contact-us">
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  etc.
</div>
```

There are also one page templates available for Joomla, some of which have extra navigation features (e.g. buttons and smooth scrolling between sections).

Extensions e.g. [Scroll To CK](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/scroll-to-ck) are also available to help with smooth scrolling.

An example of a free Joomla one page template is the [Amara](http://demo.warptheme.com/joomla/wt_amara/) template from Warp Theme.

An example of a one page Helix 3 template is [Qubic](http://demo.joomshaper.com/?template=qubic).

Note that one page websites aren't necessarily a good idea from a search engine optimisation point of view.

Answer (score 1):

should be possible with the t3 framework  http://www.t3-framework.org/ and a core template.
For the homepage you can set the template the way you want it,even without menubar if you want to.
it's even possible to run Joomla on this framework in bootstrap 3 in the frontend. no problem..

Comment: I still need menu bar, for easier navigate. I choose helix 3 framework, because it has responsive menu header, so, user will be easily navigate to another section by selecting menu bar. It's good thought for one page site.